# Excel reading lines with no data and then jump over this line

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my code. I need it to read cost center and material number, and look these up in a SAP system. It does this perfectly. The problem is that users should be able to manually enter materials and prices, with no cost center and material number also.

The program should see this line and move on to the next line. Right now it stops loading info from the SAP system, when it encounters an empty line. I know why it does this, but I can't seem to figure out how to correct it. You can see the code below. The problem is the "While" statement.

```
Sub StartExtract()
    Dim currentline As Integer

    ' This is the system to connect to
    W_System = "PE1400"
    ' We start looking for order numbers from line 6 in the sheet
    currentline = 6
    While Cells(currentline, 1).Value <> ""
            ' Run the actual GUI script
            RunGUIScript currentline
        ' move to the next line
        currentline = currentline + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider changing your loop type. you know the "why" for the stop, the while loop condition ends. Change it, define the max to iterate, and use a for loop instead. such as `for x = min to max` then within the loop put a condition to skip over such as `if cells(x,1) <> "" then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Zerk!
i tried rewriting my code to correspond with you suggestion, and this ended up working:

```
Sub StartExtract()
Dim currentline As Integer
Dim i As Long

    ' This is the system to connect to
    W_System = "PE1400"
    ' We start looking for order numbers from line 6 in the sheet
    currentline = 6
    For i = 6 To 300
        If Cells(currentline, 1).Value <> "" Then
            ' Run the actual GUI script
            RunGUIScript currentline
        ' move to the next line
        currentline = currentline + 1
        Else
        currentline = currentline + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
Option Explicit

Sub StartExtract()

    'You should really reference the Workbook and Sheet..ALWAYS
    Dim DataWS As Worksheet
    'Please insert the sheet name in which the data lies
    Set DataWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    With DataWS
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    ' This is the system to connect to
    W_System = "PE1400"
    ' We start looking for order numbers from line 6 in the sheet

    'Always want to use Long when referencing Columns or Rows
    Dim currentline As Long

    For currentline = 6 To LastRow

        If DataWS.Cells(currentline, 1).Value <> "" Then
            ' Run the actual GUI script
            RunGUIScript currentline
        End If

    Next currentline

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace the while with a `for` that goes up to the last filled line:

```
LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

for currentline = 6 to LastRow

     'if Cells(currentline,1).value<>"" then
         RunGUIScript currentline
     'end if

     'the for will automatically increment currentline
Next
```